# Как сохранить прогресс в консольной игре на Java?

Tags: java

Все знают, что при изучении программирования нужно, что-то писать. Писать калькуляторы и банкоматы надоело :)
Хочу в рамках обучения Java, написать и по мере изучения дописывать консольную игру, но если ее сделать не коротенькую, хотелось бы иметь возможность как и в любой игре сохранится и когда-то продолжить играть. 
Подскажите как это сделать или хотя бы куда смотреть ?

Comment: ну видимо в сторону записи и чтения из файла. Возможно прочитать о сиреализации.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Каким образом хранить прогресс игры?

Если тебе нужно сохранять процесс - то это безусловно запись и чтение из файла.
В Джаве это довольно просто, поэтому с освоением проблем не будет.

Также ты можешь сериализировать объект, то есть записать сущность объектов. Крутая штука, но новичку не стоит заморачиваться.

Ну а вообще, для более простого извлечения данных можно связать игру с БД или в хранить данные в xml-файле. Это очень элегантные способы извлечения и записи данных, но опять же для новичков сложновато.

## Что именно хранить?

Ты можешь сохранять значения полей (к примеру, *координаты расположения игрока, уровень, на котором остановился игрок, место сохранения и т.д*)

---

Ну, и от себя добавлю, что не стоит тратить время на масштабные консольные игры или приложения. Да, масштаб - это хорошая практика, но зачем топтаться на одном месте, если есть в языке более крутые и менее примитивные вещи, которые сделают твой код более изящным, а тебя более привлекательным на рынке труда.

Да, с примитивом интересно писать что-то необычное, особенно когда ты новичок, но когда твое детище примет дорогой стоящий вид - это совсем другое чувство.

Answer (score 2):

Можно писать в файл, но вариантов и этого способа много: просто символами, придумать свой хороший формат, добавить сжатие, можно с сериализацией побаловаться(напрямую писать объекты из кода в файл и потом восстанавливать их при считывании).

Можно использовать базу данных(но конкретно в этом случае, кажется, это далеко не самый лучший вариант).

Думаю, любой из этих вариантов, кроме тупой записи в файл, послужит хорошей обучающей задачкой на начальном этапе.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, что в вашем случае "консольной игры"   можно использовать обычный текстовый файл. Куда при "сохранении" можно закидывать данные и при "загрузке" вынимать.

Comment: Я тоже так подумал, но что конкретно я там буду хранить? А самое главное как мне заставить прогу запускаться не сначала, а в середине.

Comment: @Alex King Например значения полей объектов на момент сохранения. А когда игра будет запускаться вновь можно написать метод, который будет инициализировать поля из файла. Если у вас объектно-ориентированная игра.